# ACME certificates in Ansible using InCommon/Sectigo CA

Tags: ansible, certificate, acme

I am really struggling with getting a working Ansible playbook that utilizes the ACME protocol and the InCommon/Sectigo external account binding (EAB) and the "no challenge" option.  Lots of websites (including vendors) all say it works, but provide no working examples.

From Ansible documentation:

> So far, the ACME modules *have only been tested by the developers against Let's Encrypt, Buypass, ZeroSSL, and Pebble testing server.* **We have got community feedback that they also work with Sectigo ACME Service for InCommon.**  *If you experience problems with another ACME server ...*

Here are some pages (I am trying to use/understand):

- [Ansible Galaxy | acme_certificate](https://galaxy.ansible.com/ui/repo/published/community/crypto/content/module/acme_certificate/)
- [Ansible Galaxy | acme_account](https://galaxy.ansible.com/ui/repo/published/community/crypto/content/module/acme_account/?extIdCarryOver=true&sc_cid=701f2000001OH6uAAG)

Is there anyone who has successfully utilized an Ansible playbook, the community.crypto.acme* modules, and successfully interacted with the Sectigo/InCommon ACME service to send a CSR and have a SSL certificate produced?

**My current road-block** is incorporating the InCommon/Sectigo `external account binding (EAB)`.   I can not use “`external_account_binding`” in the “`community.crypto.acme_certificate`” calls, it just presents with an error of an invalid parameter given.

```
 "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (community.crypto.acme_certificate) module: external_account_binding. Supported parameters include: account_email, account_key_content, account_key_passphrase, account_key_src, account_uri, acme_directory, acme_version, agreement, chain_dest, challenge, csr, csr_content, data, deactivate_authzs, dest, force, fullchain_dest, modify_account, remaining_days, request_timeout, retrieve_all_alternates, select_chain, select_crypto_backend, terms_agreed, validate_certs (account_key, cert, chain, fullchain, src).",
```

The only module that supports the EAB is “`community.crypto.acme_account`”.

In that module it refers to the “`account_key_content`” which is says is the "`Content of the ACME account RSA or Elliptic Curve key.`”   Where do I find that?   It is not anywhere in the Sectigo GUI for ACME accounts, and I can find nothing the explains what it is or where to find it or calculate it?   In my code below, I just fed it the private key of the certificate I am trying to generate.. but I know that is wrong, and of course it told me as such..

```
TASK [Get Account URI] *********************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Account does not exist or is deactivated.", "other": {}}
```

Here is my non-working code:

```
- name: Get Account URI
  community.crypto.acme_account:
    account_key_content: "{{ cert_privatekey }}"
    acme_directory: "{{ acme_url }}"
    acme_version: "{{ acme_version }}"
    allow_creation: false
    state: present
    external_account_binding:
      alg: HS256
      key: "{{ acme_hmac_key }}"
      kid: "{{ acme_account_id }}"
  register: the_account_uri

# DEBUG: Output the_account_uri?
- name: Output the_account_uri?
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ the_account_uri }}"


- name: Create a challenge for sample.com using a account key file
  community.crypto.acme_certificate:
    account_key_content: "{{ cert_privatekey }}"
    csr_content: "{{ cert_csr }}"
    account_email: "{{ acme_account_email }}"
    acme_version: "{{ acme_version }}"
    acme_directory: "{{ acme_url }}"
    remaining_days: "{{ cert_term_length }}"
    dest: "/var/tmp/{{ cert_filename }}"
    challenge: no challenge
  register: acme_no_challenge
  no_log: false

# DEBUG: Output challenge?
- name: Output challenge?
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ acme_no_challenge }}"

- name: Retrieve the cert and intermediate certificate
  community.crypto.acme_certificate:
    account_key_content: "{{ cert_privatekey }}"
    csr_content: "{{ cert_csr }}"
    account_email: "{{ acme_account_email }}"
    acme_version: "{{ acme_version }}"
    challenge: no challenge
    data: "{{ acme_no_challenge }}"
    acme_directory: "{{ acme_url }}"
    remaining_days: "{{ cert_term_length }}"
    dest: "/var/tmp/{{ cert_filename }}"
    chain_dest: "{{ chain_filename }}"
    fullchain_dest: "{{ full_chain_filename }}"
  when: acme_no_challenge is changed
  no_log: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully implemented the ACME certificate renewal via Ansible.  I was able to figure it out over time and with lots of different people assisting and lots of Google foo.

Breaking it down:
Create a private/public key combination.
You first need to call acme_account, and register the private key with the Sectigo EAB credentials.
With the private key registered, you can now call acme_certificate with the account_key (private key) and all other relevant certificate generation parameters.
The certificate is generated, and then proceed to save it or install it using additional playbook plays/statements.

WORKING CODE:

```
 - name: Perform Sectigo EAB with private key, get acct URI
      community.crypto.acme_account:
        account_key_content: "{{ acct_privatekey }}"
        acme_directory: "{{ acme_url }}"
        state: present
        terms_agreed: true
        acme_version: "{{ acme_version }}"
        contact:
          - "mailto:{{ cert_group_email }}"
        external_account_binding:
          alg: HS256
          key: "{{ acme_hmac_key }}"
          kid: "{{ acme_account_id }}"
      register: acct_registration

    # DEBUG: Output the_account_uri?
    - name: Output the_account_uri?
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ acct_registration }}"

    - name: Setup the account "no challenge" using account private key
      community.crypto.acme_certificate:
        account_key_content: "{{ acct_privatekey }}"
        csr_content: "{{ cert_csr }}"
        account_email: "{{ acme_account_email }}"
        acme_version: "{{ acme_version }}"
        account_uri: "{{ acct_registration.account_uri }}"
        acme_directory: "{{ acme_url }}"
        remaining_days: "{{ cert_term_length }}"
        dest: "/var/tmp/{{ cert_filename }}"
        terms_agreed: true
        validate_certs: true
        challenge: no challenge
      register: acme_no_challenge
      no_log: false

    # DEBUG: Output challenge?
    - name: Output challenge?
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ acme_no_challenge }}"

    - name: Retrieve the cert and intermediate certificate
      community.crypto.acme_certificate:
        account_key_content: "{{ acct_privatekey }}"
        csr_content: "{{ cert_csr }}"
        account_email: "{{ acme_account_email }}"
        acme_version: "{{ acme_version }}"
        challenge: no challenge
        data: "{{ acme_no_challenge }}"
        account_uri: "{{ acct_registration.account_uri }}"
        acme_directory: "{{ acme_url }}"
        remaining_days: "{{ cert_term_length }}"
        dest: "/var/tmp/{{ cert_filename }}"
        chain_dest: "{{ chain_filename }}"
        fullchain_dest: "{{ full_chain_filename }}"
      when: acme_no_challenge is changed
      no_log: false
```